# Find the first 6 terms of Laurent Series of $f(z)=\sin(\frac{1}{1-z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the first 6 terms of Laurent Series of $f(z)=\sin(\frac{1}{1-z})$

**My attempt:**

We need the Laurent expansion of the function $f(z)=\sin(\frac{1}{1-z})$

Note: $\sin(\frac{1}{1-z})=\sin(-\frac{1}{z-1})=-\sin(\frac{1}{z-1})$ this function isn't analytic in z=1.

The representation of the $\sin$ function around of $z=1$ is:

$\sin(z-1)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(z-1)^{2n+1}$

Then:

$-\sin(\frac{1}{z-1})=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}(\frac{1}{z-1})^{2n+1}=-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}({z-1})^{-2n-1}$

Then the first 6 terms are the first 6 terms of the sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}({z-1})^{-2n-1}$ is correct?

Comment: Asking just for "The Laurent series" is ambiguous. Evidently you really want the Laurent  series "centered at $z=1$" (as opposed to for example the series centered at the origin, $\sum a_n z^n$.)

Comment: It appears to be correct.